# native bat species residing in the trees

Tags: meaning-in-context, definite-article

My freelancer, who is native speaker, wrote this sentence. Does the use of "native" mean that those bats were born in trees? Is "the" necessary? I think it unnecessary.

> Clearing forests for housing development may displace **native** bat
> species residing in **the** trees.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A native species is one that naturally lives in that region (as opposed to a species imported from overseas). It is important that such species should not be deprived of their habitat (the surroundings they naturally live in).

'**The** trees' refers to the ones that are removed when forests are cleared.

Comment: Thank you for your clarity.